# Stability of rotating limit cycle (ODE)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, stability-in-odes

Please, I need help or hint.

For the following system of ODEs:

\begin{equation}
\dot{x} = -y+x \left(r^4-3r^2+1 \right) \\
\dot{y} = x+y \left(r^4-3r^2+1 \right)
\end{equation}

where $r^2 = x^2 + y^2$. So, as a function of $x$ and $y$:

\begin{equation}
\dot{x} = x^4 y + 2 x^2 y^3 - 3 x^2 y + x + y^5 - 3 y^3 + y \\
\dot{y} = x^5 + 2 x^3 y^2 - 3 x^3 + x y^4 - 3 x y^2 + x - y
\end{equation}

How do I find stable / unstable limit cycle if I know that polynomial

\begin{equation}
x^4-3x^2+1
\end{equation}

has 4 roots:

\begin{equation}
x_1=\dfrac{1}{2} \pm \dfrac{\sqrt{5}}{2} \\
x_2= -\dfrac{1}{2} \pm \dfrac{\sqrt{5}}{2}
\end{equation}

variable $\:r\:$ in the $\:\dot{x}, \dot{y}\:$ represents polar coordinates.

I have determined $\:\dot{r}=r^5-3r^3+r\:$ and $\:\dot{\varphi} = 1\:$ to analyze equilibria point [0,0] behavior, but I don't knowing that helps in this case.

Comment: @Moo I have updated the post with $(\dot{x})=f(x,y)$ , $(\dot{y})=f(x,y)$.

Comment: Actually, the fist two equation for $x^{\prime}$ and $y^{\prime}$ are an official problem, so there's no mistake. The $r$ being in the $x^{\prime}$ and $y^{\prime}$ is sort of a hint for easier problem's solving in polar coordinates. After rewrite the ODEs: \begin{equation} x^{\prime} = -r\sin\varphi+ r\cos\varphi \left(r^4 - 3r^2 + 1 \right) \\ y^{\prime} = r\cos\varphi+ r\sin\varphi \left(r^4 - 3r^2 + 1 \right) \end{equation} . I don't think so that solving the system in Cartesian is a good thing to do, but I might be wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$r$ as component of the polar coordinates is always positive. Thus you can ignore the negative roots. From $rr'=xx'+yy'$ you get the radius dynamic
$$
r'=r(r^4−3r^2+1)=r(r^2+r-1)(r^2-r-1)
$$
The sign of $r'$ is positive for small $r$, then negative after the first positive root $\frac{\sqrt5-1}2$, then positive again after the second positive root $\frac{\sqrt5+1}2$. In forward time, this means that $r$ is growing on the first segment, falling on the second, and growing again on the final segment, making the first positive root a stable equilibrium (for the radius) and the second an unstable one.

Comment: Thanks! So, the first one $r_1 = 1/2 + \sqrt{5}/2$ would be a stable limit cycle and the second one $r_2 = -1/2 + \sqrt{5}/2$  unstable? However, I have to apologize, that I have mixed the problem description a bit. The question should be "How do I find stable / unstable limit cycle if I know that polynomial $x^4 - 3x^2 +1$ has those 4 roots: $x_1$, $x_2$... I'm not sure whether it doesn't change the situation. I have updated the post. Sorry!

Comment: @JoshE. : You might want to check which one is the smaller root, it seems as if $r_2<r_1$, so you have to switch the order. // Your change of the question is more to the worse, as you now have $x$ used in two different, independent roles, once as coordinate and once as the variable of a polynomial. There is no reason not to keep using $r$ for the second role, or to use a completely different letter.

Comment: I see. I have the question to the exact exercise wording. I think I got your point. So, if I should determine which system cycles are stable and which unstable, then trajectory defined by radius of bigger root is stable, because the sign is positive and unstable trajectory has radius of smaller positive $r$, because the sign is negative? I'm sorry for so many questions... I thought I understood the limit cycles of ODEs, but this question really confused me.

Comment: It is the sign change at the root that determines local behavior and thus stability. A sign change from positive to negative gives stability.